# dynamically create and populate accordian with JQuery, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

========== **STILL NEED HELP SEE UPDATE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE** ==========

i want to create accordion based on how many year exist in my database

my table looks like this

```
 No | Course Code | Course name | Year
 1  | CC1         | CN1         | 2015
 2  | CC2         | CN2         | 2016
 3  | CC3         | CN3         | 2017
```

as u can see there are 3 different years so i want to make 3 accordion and populate each accordion based on the year data, i believe we can do this use jquery but i don't have the logic since i'm new

> **this is my controller**

```
public function getYear(){
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT year FROM Subject');
    $number = $query->num_rows();//this is to get how many year in my table
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= $no){
       //do something????    
    $i++;
    }
}
public function history_list_data(){//function statically populate list_data
    $data['get_data'] = $this->cms_dosen_m->getHistoryDosen()->result();
    $this->load->view('cms_dosen/history/list_data',$data);
}
```

> JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#list_data').load("<?php echo site_url('cms_dosen/history_list_data') ?>");
    });
</script>
```

the JQuery above only can make a static accordion and populate all the data without filter it by year

i believe we can use something called `append` in JS but until now i don't know how it is work and also how to parse how many year i have to this so called 'append'

========================= **UPDATE** =========================

i already manage to make an dynamic accordion based on year by using following code

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="banyakTahun" id="manyTahun" value="<?php echo $many_year?>">
        </div>
    <?php
        $i = 1 ;
        foreach ($year as $rows) : ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default"> 
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a id="<?php echo 'cobaDy'.$i;?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo 'hiddenValue'.$i?>" value="<?php echo $rows->ta?>" name="">Tahun Ajaran&nbsp <?php echo $rows->ta?></i>
                </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="list_data"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $i++?>
    <?php endforeach?>
```

i put hidden value in my `foreach`but if i try to get it with alert in JS it always give me the value of 2017, does anyone know how to solve it? my JS comes like this

> JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cobaDy').click(function(){
       var value =  $('#hiddenValue').val();
       /*var value = $(this).val();*/
       alert(value);
    })
 })
</script>
```

========================= **UPDATE** =========================

i manage to get the value of each loop and create an accordion based how many years i have in my table, now i face another problem, there are 2 problems that im facing right now

1. the way im parse my data is not smooth enough
2. i want when i click accordian `A`, the accordion that not been clicked will automatically close, but i fail to do so, every time i open 1 accordion, i need to close it first then open another one

> JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var many = $("#manyTahun").val();
    for($i=1;$i<=many;$i++){
        $('#hiddenValue'+$i).click(function(){
            $.post(
                '<?php echo site_url("cms_dosen/history_list_data");?>',
                {'fak_id':$(this).val()},
                function(data){
                    $("#list_data").html(data);
                }
            );
        }) 
    }
 });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @deg i get it how to simple append something but i don't know how to make a loop for it, more likely i don't get it how to parse number in my controller to JQuery to make a loop for it